# list-style-image not applied properly in .accordion .accordion-title

Tags: html, css

I'm trying apply this CSS property:

```
.accordion .accordion-title {
    list-style-image: url("images/btn_mas.png") !important;
}
```

To each `h3.accordion-title` inside `div.accordion` on [this page](http://wp4.jurisprudencialaboral.com/legislacion/una-legislacion-nueva/). The idea is to have something like this:

[image]

Where LI items gets a image and that image change on hover for another one lets said for one called `btn_menos.png` but I can't get it to work as you can see on the page. What I'm doing wrong? Any advice? How Ic can achieve that?

**Note:** I can't change how the HTML for the item is generated so it's required to work with that markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant add `list-style-image` to an `h3`. Those are reserved for `li` tags. What you should do instead is add the image as a `background` to the the `span` that wraps that text like so:

```
.accordion .accordion-title span {
    color: #868a8c;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: url(images/btn_mas.png) no-repeat 0px 8px; //add
    padding: 0 0 0 25px; //add
}
```

Comment: And how do I change the `:hover` state? Using `.accordion .accordion-title span:hover`?

Comment: Yep exactly, then add some new styles